# Definition of Frobenius morphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory

Let $k$ be algebraic closed field such that characteristic is $p.$

Now we have Frobenius morphism $f:\mathbb{A}_k^1\to \mathbb{A}_k^1,  f(a)＝a^p$.

$f$ is correspond to ring morphism $\phi:k[x]\to k[x]$.

But what is $\phi$？ please tell me, thanks.

Comment: There are several notions of Frobenius. Arithmetic, geometric, absolute,... I am quite unsure about the one you are describing actually. After all, the map $f:\mathbb{A}^1\to\mathbb{A}^1, a\mapsto a^p$ does not require $k$ of characteristic $p$. Can you provide more context ?

Comment: Sorry, I think this by R.Hartshorne’s algebraic geometry I.Excersice.3.2.  But I don’t almost know kind of Frobenius morphism.

Comment: I see, so indeed the map does not require $k$ of characteristic $p$, but you need to show that it induces a homeomorphism of the underlying spaces and this is where the characteristic $p$ is needed. So the map is just $k[x]\to k[x], x\mapsto x^p$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think  more time by your hint.